# How can I change the send button color on hover in dialogflow messenger

Tags: css, dialogflow-es

Here's my code:

```
window.addEventListener("dfMessengerLoaded", function (event) {
        const dfMessenger = document.querySelector("df-messenger");
        const dfMessengerChat =
          dfMessenger.shadowRoot.querySelector("df-messenger-chat");

        const sheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
        sheet.replaceSync(`
  div.chat-wrapper.chat-open { height: auto; width: 400px; max-height: 450px; }
`);

        const sheet2 = new CSSStyleSheet();
        sheet2.replaceSync(`
  df-messenger-user-input:hover #sendIcon { fill: blue; }
`);

        dfMessengerChat.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [
          ...dfMessengerChat.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets,
          sheet,
          sheet2,
        ];
})
```